# El contador no funciona en c

Tags: c

les presento mi problema, yo tengo este struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char nombre[20];
    unsigned int dni;
    tfecha nac;
}tperfil;

typedef struct
{
    int d, m, a;
}tfecha;
```

del cual tengo un array del mismo y la idea del contador es frenar cuando se encuentra con un 99 en el campo DIA (a[u].nac.d). Ya que yo anteriormente tengo codigo que agrega 99 al campo de DIA cuando no hay mas datos para poder realizar un corte de control.

```
int control(const tperfil a[])
{
    int u = 0;
    printf("%u %i\n", a[15].nac.d, u);
    while(a[u].nac.d < 99)
    {
        printf("%u %i\n", a[u].nac.d, u);
        u++;
    }
    return u;
}
```

Yo ya se que en el a[15] hay un 99 en ese campo, el problema que aparece es que como se puede ver en el primer printf, me muestra el 99 como deberia ser, pero el segundo printf que es el que me muestra el recorrido me muestra:

```
23 0
14 1
4 2
25 3
12 4
22 5
31 6
17 7
22 8
4 9
2 10
23 11
15 12
14 13
14 14
420070599 0
23 0
14 1
4 2
25 3
12 4
22 5
31 6
17 7
22 8
4 9
2 10
23 11
15 12
14 13
14 14
```

no entiendo porque en la posición 15 me lee ese numero y no el 99 que antes me mostraba correctamente. El programa crashea.

Comment: Hola Martín. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. El mensaje que imprimes no es coherente con el código que adjuntas, ya que mencionas que hay dos ciclos que se imprimen pero en realidad sólo hay uno. Adicional a eso, ¿de qué tamaño es el arreglo a que envías como argumento a la función control()?

Comment: Hola, el arreglo es de tamaño 16, de 0 a 15 y en la ultima posición esta el 99, en cuanto a los printf, el primero no esta en ciclo, solo lo agregue para corroborar el valor de esa posición antes de que entre en el ciclo, y me lo imprime correectamente al 99, el problema surge cuando entra en el while que  no lee el 99 que anteriormente lo habia hecho. No le encuentro explicación.

Comment: Martín, es claro que imprimirá el 99 al invocar el primer `prinff` fuera del ciclo while y **no** lo imprimirá dentro del ciclo `while` porque no cumple la condición para imprimirse. En tu ciclo while exiges que para imprimir el valor de a[u].nac.d  debe ser menor a 99, y es claro que para tu último caso a[u].nac.d no es mayor ni menor a 99, sino igual, por lo tanto la condición no se cumple y el resultado esperado en efecto es que no imprime el valor de esa posición dle arreglo.

Comment: Si ese es el caso no deberia entrar al while directamente porque no cumple la condicion, pero en cambio sigue leyendo numeros y reseteando el valor de u hasta que crashea. Es claro que no deberia leer el 99, de hecho no deberia leer nada mas y devolver el valor de u, no?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías primero incrementar y después imprimir, pues cuando a[u].nac.d == 99 termina el siclo y no da oportunidad a imprimirse.

```
while(a[u].nac.d != 99)
{
    u++;
    printf("%u %i\n", a[u].nac.d, u);
}
```

Comment: ocurre exactamente lo mismo, gracias igual por la opcion

Comment: Ya lo veo, deberías primero incrementar y después imprimir, pues cuando   a[u].nac.d == 99 termina el siclo y no da oportunidad a imprimirse.

Comment: El problema surge cuando llega a la posición que contiene el 99 y continua el ciclo porque de alguna manera no esta leyendo un 99, sino un  420070599

Comment: ¿Cuando debería detenerse el ciclo?

Comment: Cuando u=14; ya que en la posición 15 esta el 99. Lo que sucede es que lee ese numero extraño. y vuelve a comenzar el ciclo en 0, hasta que vuelve a al 15 y crashea.

Comment: Eso no me suena a un error del while, parece más un error al declarar una variable o al asignar valores, una vez me pasó algo así por no inicializar un int ¿Podrias subir el código entero? aunque realmente recomendaría publicar na nueva pregunta, pues está ya se está complicando mucho.

Comment: El código tiene 276 lineas, complicaria mucho subirlo, de cualquier manera revisare las asignaciones si hay algun error.

Comment: Un consejo, en lugar de declarar como:

     `int d, m, a;`

deberías declarar:

`int d;
int m;
int a;`

No creo que sea ese el error , pero es una simple convención. Aunque quien sabe.

Answer (score -1):

Si hay un 99 en el `a[15]` como dices, no debería entrar en el ciclo while.

```
while(a[u].nac.d < 99)
```

Comment: exacto, pero como dije anteriormente el primer print f me muestra el campo de a[15] y efectivamente me muestra el 99, pero cuando entra al while en esa posicion aparece el 420070599